# Customize Filter Panel Footer - MUI DataGrid Pro

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I customize the MUI filter panel WITHOUT creating an entire custom filter panel? Ideally, I would like to add a custom panel filter footer component. I want to add a button next to the "Add Filter" button.

```
components={{
  Toolbar: CustomToolBar,
  Footer: CustomFooter, 
  FilterPanelFooter: CustomFilterPanelFooter // Like this
}}
```

Since new data is constantly being added, I would like to add a button that will refresh my current filters.

[image]